# Erro Python com Django on_delete

Tags: python, python-3.x, django-2.0

Sou iniciante na plataforma Django e na linguagem Python e, estou desenvolvendo um site em Django 2.2 e Python 3.7.3,
e estou com um problema no meu código no `models.py` da minha app "courses".

```
class Enrollment(models.Model):

    STATUS_CHOICES = (
        (0, 'Pendente'),
        (1, 'Aprovado'),
        (2, 'Cancelado'),
    )

    user = models.ForeignKey(
        settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, verbose_name='Usuário',
        models.CASCADE,
        related_name='enrollments'
    )
    course = models.ForeignKey(
        Course, verbose_name='Curso', related_name='enrollments'
    )
    status = models.IntegerField(
        'Situação', choices=STATUS_CHOICES, default=1, blank=True
    )

    created_at = models.DateTimeField('Criado em', auto_now_add=True)
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField('Atualizado em', auto_now=True)

    def active(self):
        self.status = 1
        self.save()

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Inscrição'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Inscrições'
        unique_together = (('user', 'course'),)
```

E está dando esse erro:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 21, in <module>
    main()
  File "manage.py", line 17, in main
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ambientes_virtuais\virtual_01\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ambientes_virtuais\virtual_01\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 357, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ambientes_virtuais\virtual_01\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ambientes_virtuais\virtual_01\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ambientes_virtuais\virtual_01\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ambientes_virtuais\virtual_01\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ConnectU\ConnectU\courses\models.py", line 53, in <module>
    class Enrollment(models.Model):
  File "C:\Users\Luciano\ambientes_virtuais\ConnectU\ConnectU\courses\models.py", line 67, in Enrollment
    Course, verbose_name='Curso', related_name='enrollments'
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'on_delete'
```

O que eu posso fazer?

Answer (score 1):

Felipe, se você verificar a documentação do campo [`Model.ForeignKey`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#foreignkey) verá que a assinatura do método é:

```
ForeignKey(to, on_delete, **options)
```

E verificando o [código fonte](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/_modules/django/db/models/fields/related/#ForeignKey) temos o construtor:

```
def __init__(self, to, on_delete, related_name=None, related_query_name=None,
             limit_choices_to=None, parent_link=False, to_field=None,
             db_constraint=True, **kwargs):
    ...
```

Isso significa que há dois parâmetros obrigatórios, `to` e `on_delete`, o restante é opcional. No seu model você faz:

```
user = models.ForeignKey(
    settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
    verbose_name='Usuário',
    models.CASCADE,
    related_name='enrollments'
)
course = models.ForeignKey(
    Course, verbose_name='Curso', related_name='enrollments'
)
```

Se você reparar verá que em `user` você está chamando `models.ForeignKey` usando:

1. Um argumento posicional com o valor `settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`
2. Um argumento nomeado `verbose_name` com o valor `"Usuário"`
3. Um argumento posicional com o valor `models.CASCADE`
4. Um argumento nomeado `related_name` com o valor `"enrollments"`

Você não pode intercalar argumentos nomeados e posicionais ao chamar uma função. Você deve passar os argumentos posicionais antes dos nomeados. E como mostrado no código fonte e na documentação os argumentos são `to` e  `on_delete`, então você precisa alterar seu código para que estes parâmetros sejam passados corretamente:

1. Passando o parâmetro `on_delete` logo após o parâmetro `to`:

   ```
   user = models.ForeignKey(
       settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
       models.CASCADE,
       verbose_name='Usuário',
       related_name='enrollments'
   )
   ```
2. Passando o parâmetro `on_delete` em nomeando-o:

   ```
   user = models.ForeignKey(
       settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, 
       verbose_name='Usuário',
       on_delete=models.CASCADE,
       related_name='enrollments'
   )
   ```